# Desencriptar password con bcryptjs en Node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy consultando el usuario median el módulo [mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) para traer la contraseña y compararlo con en el hash mediante [bcrypt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js) para poder iniciar sesión.

Este es el código para autenticar:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var sql = require('mssql');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(usuario, done) {
        done(null, usuario);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function(req, Sk_Codigo_Usuario, Sk_Clave, done) {

        var config = require('.././database/config');

        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function() {
                var request = new sql.Request();
                request.query("SELECT Sk_Codigo_Usuario, Sk_Nombre, Sk_Clave FROM Sk_Usuarios WHERE Sk_Codigo_Usuario = '" + req.body.username + "'")
                    .then(function(recordset) {

                            var usuario = recordset[0];
                            if (bcrypt.compareSync(Sk_Clave, usuario.Sk_Clave)) {
                                return done(null, {
                                    Sk_Nombre: usuario.Sk_Nombre,
                                    Sk_Codigo_Usuario: usuario.Sk_Codigo_Usuario
                                });
                            }

                        sql.close();
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('authmessage', 'Usuario o Password incorrecto.'));

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });
    }));

};
```

La ejecutar la aplicación, la consola me dice el siguiente error:

> Request error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Sk_Clave' of undefined

Gracias.

Comment: El error salta porque `recordset[0]` es undefined. Prueba a hacer `console.log` con `recordset` y debugea.

Comment: Ya lo arregle es de esta forma  `var usuario = recordset['recordset'];` pero ahora me aparece el siguiente error `Request error: Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined`

Comment: `Sk_Codigo_Usuario` sigue siendo `undefined`.

Comment: Debes de poner un breakpoint en donde te da error, acostúmbrate a depurar tus aplicaciones para encontrar errores/bugs rápidamente.

Comment: Si los trae, pero al momento de entrar al `if (bcrypt.compareSync(Sk_Clave, usuario.Sk_Clave)) {
                                return done(null, {
                                    Sk_Nombre: usuario.Sk_Nombre,
                                    Sk_Codigo_Usuario: usuario.Sk_Codigo_Usuario
                                });
                            }`  ya dice que esta undefined

Comment: ¿Has hecho un `console.log` de `Sk_Clave` y `usuario.Sk_Clave`?

Comment: Si le haga un `console.log` a usuario me trae lo siguiente `[ { Sk_Codigo_Usuario: 'Admin',
    Sk_Nombre: 'Admin',
    Sk_Clave: '93202F490927C71682AAA17D53E7EC28AABE8C9B' } ]`, pero si le hago un `console.log` a usuar.Sk_Clave` ya me dice que es undefined,  No entiendo.

Comment: Es porque `usuario` es un array, no un objeto. Debes hacer lo siguiente: `const usuario = recordset[0][0];`.

Comment: Por favor trata de marcar las respuestas que te ayudan para tener más orden; hay un buen % de tus preguntas sin evaluar.

Comment: Ya me aparece es el siguiente error     `throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${originalStatusCode}`);`